# What are general rules to form this superlatives: "adjective + most"?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

I happen to find superlatives with the structure below:

Adjective + most,

which are:
 the rearmost, the frontmost, the uppermost, the headmost, the outermost, the topmost, etc.

What are the general rules to form this type of superlative? Is it related to direction?

Comment: Matt, I actually find "outmost" in Oxford dictionary. Do we normally use "outermost" because "outmost" is considered archaic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean the latest point reachable when you move in a certain direction:

- rightmost -> move right until you can't move anymore
- headmost -> move ahead until you can't move anymore

and so on.

The point you've reached when you can't move anymore is the point the speaker is talking about.

So in general:

- "direction"most -> move in "direction" until you can't move anymore. You will see what I mean there

Comment: [Utmost?](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/utmost) [Uttermost?](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uttermost&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: Good idea :-). The "ut" in "utmost" is an old form of "out", so it's a direction in that sense too. It's going to the point the furthest out.

Answer (score 0):

The "general rule" to form an "Adjective + most" superlative is, tack on *most* after an adjective, and see if it's meaningful and sounds right; which is how most such words were formed.  There are some interesting "misformed" exceptions, for example *[foremost](http://www.wordswarm.net/dictionary/foremost.html)* which derives as a corruption or variant of *formest* or *[fyrmest](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=foremost)*, "altered on the assumption that it is a compound of fore and most."

*[Most](http://www.wordswarm.net/dictionary/most.html)* itself is a superlative of *much, many,* or *more* (but is sometimes used colloquially in place of *almost*).  As a suffix, it lends a "most extreme" meaning, in the same sense or "direction" suggested by the word it suffixes.